# Dynamic array push() in C causes Valgrind error

Tags: c, dynamic, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

Im trying to create a function in C with three input parameters. Dynamic array if integers, its length and integer number. The function will increase the size of dynamic array by one element and put integer number (parameter) as a new element at its end. There is a really simple code, which works, but generates a memory leak error in Valgrind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pushINT(int*arr,int*size,int data) {
    int*tmp=realloc(arr,(*size+1)*sizeof(int));
    if(tmp==NULL)exit(100);
    else {
        arr[*size]=data;
        (*size)=*size+1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int* array=malloc(0);
    int arraySIZ=0;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) pushINT(array,&arraySIZ,i);
    for(int i=0;i<arraySIZ;i++) printf("%d",array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==19581== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19581== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19581== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19581== Command: /home/filip/Documents/b3b36PRG/HW05/main.c
==19581== 
/home/filip/Documents/b3b36PRG/HW05/main.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/filip/Documents/b3b36PRG/HW05/main.c: line 4: `void pushINT(int*arr,int*size,int data) {'
==19581== 
==19581== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19581==     in use at exit: 83,410 bytes in 2,151 blocks
==19581==   total heap usage: 3,812 allocs, 1,661 frees, 145,949 bytes allocated
==19581== 
==19581== 109 (32 direct, 77 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 619 of 690
==19581==    at 0x483880B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==19581==    by 0x192341: xmalloc (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x146EEE: make_bare_simple_command (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x146FC5: make_simple_command (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x141C5B: yyparse (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x1380C9: parse_command (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x1381D7: read_command (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x13845F: reader_loop (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581==    by 0x136B68: main (in /usr/bin/bash)
==19581== 
==19581== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19581==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==19581==    indirectly lost: 77 bytes in 5 blocks
==19581==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19581==    still reachable: 83,301 bytes in 2,145 blocks
==19581==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19581== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==19581== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==19581== 
==19581== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19581== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What causes this problem? I suspect realloc().

Comment: `int *arr` passes a pointer to the array, but when you modify that pointer value, it cannot be seen by the caller. QED. Use `int**arr`.

Comment: The code you show in the question bears no resemblance to the Valgrind leak trace.   The only function in common is `main()`, which isn't saying very much.  There's nothing we can do to help you until you show us the trace from the code you show us.  (Please don't show the Bison code with `yyparse` etc; that's rather big.)

Comment: How should then a call of the function from the main() look like? I tied int**arr but got with similar error.

Comment: You ran Valgrind on `main.c` instead of the executable compiled from `main.c` — witness the error message about `/home/filip/Documents/b3b36PRG/HW05/main.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('` and the leak trace information identifying `/usr/bin/bash` (which had me puzzled when I first commented — I should have spent longer being puzzled).  You need to run something like `valgrind ./your_program` to get the memory trace from your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should be:

```
void pushINT(int **arr,int *size,int data) {
    int *tmp=realloc(*arr,(*size+1)*sizeof(int));
    if (tmp==NULL) exit(100);
    *arr= tmp;
    tmp[*size]=data;
    (*size)=*size+1;
}
```

Note it now receives a double pointer and remember that `realloc` can change the memory location. Therefore it is necessary to update the caller's pointer, the reason why it needs a double pointer.

---

Or as Jonathan Leffler suggests:

```
int *pushINT(int *arr,int *size,int data) {
    int *tmp=realloc(arr,(*size+1)*sizeof(int));
    if (tmp==NULL) exit(100);
    tmp[*size]=data;
    (*size)=*size+1;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to make the function return the modified value: `int *pushINT(int *arr, int *size, int data) { …; return tmp; }` and then use `array = pushINT(array, &arraySIZ, i);`.  I wonder if it's worth noting that adding one at a time can lead to quadratic behaviour; it's better to double the number of items in the array, but then you probably need a structure to encapsulate 3 pieces of information: the base address, the allocated space, and the used space.